# How can I use rspec with YAML fixtures that get cleaned up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures

I want my rspec tests to load my YAML fixtures, and I want them to be loaded inside the transaction, so that they disappear after each test.

```
describe "the thing I'm testing"
   fixtures :sandwiches, :condiments

   before(:each) do
      # stuff
   end

   it "makes sandwiches"
      # making sandwiches 
   end
end
```

When the call to `fixtures` is there (in the `describe` block, but not in the `before` block), it loads my sandwiches and condiments, but outside of the transaction, and thus committed. Well, it looks that way; what's certain is that my fixtures are still in the db after the test finishes.

I thought perhaps I could put the call to `fixtures` in the `before` block, inside the transaction, but then I get

> NoMethodError: undefined method `fixtures' for 
>   <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fd1f11f7578>

So I guess I could use DatabaseCleaner, or something similar, but...can't I get what I want without that?

Answer (score 1):

`fixtures` is a Rails method (not RSpec) that, afaik, doesn't actually load the fixtures - just registers them for loading later.

It *is* a class method, so it has to run in the class (the `ExampleGroup` returned by describe) and not the instance in which `before`, `it`, etc are evaluated.

Do you have `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in spec_helper.rb?

Comment: I do have the config parameter, and it is running the test in a transaction, cleaning up anything my test does, except for the fixtures. Now that's true, fixtures just loads the fixtures for later, so...I wonder when it loads them.